# htaccess not working fedora 20

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora-20

My htaccess is not working on fedora

I made all AllowOverrides to be All.

I restarted the httpd.service

A site suggesting putting junk into the .htaccess file. I added it, nothing happened, suggessting htaccess isn't being read.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Since most people use htaccess for rewrites, do you have mod_rewrite enabled ?

Answer (score 3):

You may have made a typo in your question but the extremely insecure syntax is `AllowOverride All` not the plural you used.

The thing is, if you have access to the main Apache configuration 
you're better off including your configuration in the main httpd.conf instead of relying on .htaccess files, according to [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

Comment: Up for suggesting to avoid .htaccess. But if he made a configuration typo, apache would restart...

Comment: I meant I changed all AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All. Adding the rules to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf did nothing